# Is there a set which contains its own powerset?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is it possible that there is a set A (has to be inifinite) which contains its own poewr set P(A)?
A can not be a finite group, because its power set would have 2^a parts. but what about infinite groups? I've tried to find some and couldn't succeed.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not possible to have such a set $A$.

Comment: Cantor's theorem: The cardinality of a set is strictly smaller than that of its power set; this is true both for infinite and finite sets.

Comment: Make it an exercise for yourself; attempt to set up a bijection between a set and its power set

Comment: Nope.  It's a cool question though.  Try proving it yourself.  There are a bunch of ways to show it.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows I've tried, can't get a hold of it. Have any clues?

Comment: It's a consequence of Cantor's theorem but that's kind of boring.  Let 'f' be some arbitrary function between 'A' and 'P(A)'.  Try to show that 'f' is not onto or not surjective.  I haven't worked through it myself but that should do it.  You could also show that you can construct an element of 'P(A)' that is not a member of 'A'.

Answer (score 2):

You can start from Cantor's theorem that $|A| \lt |P(A)|$  Given any proposed bijection $A \leftrightarrow P(A)$ consider the subset formed by taking all the members of $A$ that are not members of the subset they are matched with.  This subset is not the image of any element of $A$.  Now in your case we have $A$ containing a strictly larger set, which is impossible.

Prompted by your comment, you can use the axiom of regularity to show this is not possible.  We have $A \subset P(A)$, so if $P(A)\subset A$ we have an infinite descending chain.  Similarly we have $A \in P(A)$, so if $P(A) \subset A$ we have $A \in A$ violating regularity.

Comment: Can I claim that A is a set of members, while P(A) is a set of set of members, and if A is a set of set of members, P(A) will be a set of set of set of members etc? meaning the set P(A) will always be 1 step "below" A in the "hierarchy"?

Comment: See my addition